# Setting field value in try{} and calling base class in finally{}

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, try-finally

I was browsing .NET Framework source code trying to understand another issue and I saw this code (in `PeerNearMe.cs` from `System.Net.PeerToPeer.Collaboration`):

```
private bool m_Disposed; 

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{ 
    if (!m_Disposed){
        try{
            m_Disposed = true;
        } 
        finally{
            base.Dispose(disposing); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to put variable assignment in `try` block? May it fail in any way with an exception?! At first I thought it's because finally will be executed even if thread is aborted with `Thread.Abort()`:

> Unexecuted finally blocks are executed before the thread is aborted.

In this case **I'd expect** try block to include all method body:

```
try {
    if (!m_disposed)
        m_disposed = true;
}
finally {
    base.Dispose(disposing)
}
```

However [they](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) also says:

> The thread that calls Abort might block if the thread that is being aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block, finally block, or constrained execution region. If the thread that calls Abort holds a lock that the aborted thread requires, a deadlock can occur.

IMO calling a base class virtual method is little bit a *jump in the dark* in this case.

In short: what's this point of that code? What it really tries to implement? If it's because of `Thread.Abort()` then isn't it just *wrong*?

**EDIT**: if it's really just because of `Thread.Abort()` then it doesn't do its job if abort happens after `if (!m_Disposed) {` but before `try {`. Note that `Dispose()` must be resilient to multiple calls and simply do nothing (regardless when it's called).

Comment: Irony - msdn suggests avoiding _ and Hungarian notation for fields and they have done it internally.

Comment: @dotnetkid, conversion is just conversion. As long as whole organization follow it, it works.

Comment: It could also be the case, that previous versions of this code had more statements before the `m_disposed = true;` statement. And that the try/finally block is merely a left-over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that can happen is an asynchronous exception - `Thread.Abort` is one example, but there's also the likes of `Thread.Interrupt` or `OutOfMemoryException`.

Your suggestion actually breaks the code, because you call `base.Dispose` regardless of whether the instance was already disposed or not - that's not the intention.

Now, `Thread.Abort` should only be used when terminating an application domain - so you don't care whether the `m_disposed = true` succeeds or not, the domain is going to be torn down soon anyway. However, you still care about releasing any native resources, because those are usually tied to the process, not the application domain (and sometimes, they even transcend processes or whole machines).

Code in `finally` gets a chance to run even in the middle of a `Thread.Abort` - there's no other way to ensure code runs during an asynchronous exception. By calling `base.Dispose` in a `finally` clause, you ensure that it at least gets a chance to execute, and that it will not be terminated in the middle of operation (though note that there's a fixed time limit for all the `finally` clauses that execute - you don't want to do anything complex in a `finally`).

Now, in this particular case, there isn't a real reason to do this - the base class doesn't do anything either. So it's probably just a common `Dispose` pattern the team uses :) Since `Dispose` is designed for deterministic release of native resources, it's perfectly safe to call it in a `finally` clause - it's not supposed to do any work, just release native resources. Of course, `Dispose` is frequently abused - but then you just reap what you've sown.

Finally, don't forget that this is also exactly what a `using` clause does, so if you're using `using`, you're already running the `Dispose` method in a `finally` clause!

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap())
{
  ...
}
```

Is translated to the equivalent of

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
try
{
  bmp = new Bitmap();

  ...
}
finally
{
  if (bmp != null) bmp.Dispose();
}
```

All in all, there's nothing suspicious about that implementation, really :)

Comment: I'd agree with you about everything but _"...breaks the code, because...that's not the intention". I mean: Dispose() must be resilient to multiple calls. If aborting happens after if (...) but before try { then base class will not be called.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The thing is, it really doesn't matter much. You should really *always* call `Dispose` in a `finally` block at some level - that's its whole purpose. This way of writing the `Dispose` method itself ensures that the base classes' `Dispose` method is called within a `finally` - which is not a bad idea, since you shouldn't depend on implementation details of your base classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about why its in a try as it's only assigning a variable, maybe someone else can tell us this.

I would say that your expectation would act differently though. Putting the whole try finally inside the if(!m_disposed) means that the object won't call Dispose if that m_disposed is true whereas your expectation would call dispose regardless of m_disposed value.

Comment: It's true but you should be able to call Dispose() multiple times without any side effect and it will call base.Dispose() also if thread is aborted after if (!m_disposed) { but before m_disposed = true.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti A lot of those guarantees no longer apply when you're unloading an application domain - and that's the only place where `Thread.Abort` should be used.

Comment: @Luaan I don't think so otherwise it's not a guarantee! If this is the purpose of this code (protect against asynchronous exceptions) then it _may_ simply fail.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti There's no 100% guarantees in C# - or any other language, really. You *must* understand the boundaries of any guarantees, otherwise you'll end up in trouble. `Thread.Abort` is one of those massive disruptors (and it didn't even allow `finally` to continue originally - that was a breaking change), as is appdomain unload, or a process kill, or a power plug being yanked from the socket. And your code doesn't help anyway - the try-finally *still* doesn't cover the whole method. That's why `Dispose` is called from a `finally` clause in most cases.

Comment: Dispose() may release per AppDomain resources. Per process resources. Per **machine** resources. Also on **another machine**. There isn't (there shouldn't be) a corner-case where it works _more or less_. If you're running on a server and your process is softly killed because (let's say) consuming too much resources then you want to release them all. Both on your machine and (especially!) on other machines. If that's the case and that pattern is used to protect against this kind of exceptions then (IMO, of course!) is just done wrong.